# How to speed up jest tests using jest.useFakeTimers or other methods?

Tags: jestjs

I have a test that should wait for a long time.

I try to use jest.useFakeTimers to speed it up.
But nothing happened

```js
 test('test timers', async () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers();
        let i = 1;
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000000));
        expect(i).toBe(1);
    });
```

What is the correct way to use jest.useFakeTimers and speed my test?

Answer (score -1):

Check out this page on jest documentation which explains how to use timers in different ways:

https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks